# Issues with fetch

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

```
const button = document.getElementById('button');

async function initialRequest() {
    const data = await fetch("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?page=1&pagesize=5&order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {return data.items});
    return data;
}

button.onclick = async (e) => {
    let questionCount = document.getElementById('limitVal');
    const value = questionCount.value;
    const data = initialRequest();
    console.log(data);
}
```

When I try running the above code block, I get a network error from this code and the browser debugger points out the closing bracket in the initialRequest function as an issue. However, when I make the request from inside the event callback, it works fine. The issue is there is a lot more code that will be going into this project and I want to split things up as much as I can.

Comment: intialRequest() is returining the promise

Comment: Yes you need to `await` it.  `const data = await initialRequest();`

Comment: Why use `then` blocks if you're using async/await?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Aniket and @Linda Paiste, adding await seems to do the trick for me. See example:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');

async function initialRequest() {
    const data = await fetch("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?page=1&pagesize=5&order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {return data.items});
    return data;
}

button.onclick = async (e) => {
    // let questionCount = document.getElementById('limitVal');
    // const value = questionCount.value;
    const data = await initialRequest();
    console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Button</button>
```